# sbt heapsize not enough?

Tags: scala, sbt, heap-memory

When i try to compile [scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart) i get a OutOfMemoryError:

```
> compile
[info] 
[info] == compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 127 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling main sources...
[info] == compile ==
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.Tuple2$Zipped.map(Tuple2.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:3134)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeMap.mapOver(Types.scala:3024)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$SubstMap.apply(Types.scala:3455)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.subst(Types.scala:580)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$Type.instantiateTypeParams(Types.scala:421)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.exprTypeArgs(Infer.scala:449)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.inferExprInstance(Infer.scala:1103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:738)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:732)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit1(Implicits.scala:484)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit0(Implicits.scala:449)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Implicits$ImplicitSearch$$typedImplicit(Implicits.scala:376)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.tryImplicitInfo$1(Implicits.scala:668)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.rankImplicits(Implicits.scala:671)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.findBest(Implicits.scala:695)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.searchImplicit(Implicits.scala:753)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.implicitManifestOrOfExpectedType(Implicits.scala:1069)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.bestImplicit(Implicits.scala:1096)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$class.inferImplicit(Implicits.scala:57)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$analyzer$.inferImplicit(Global.scala:347)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$applyImplicitArgs$1.apply(Typers.scala:120)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$applyImplicitArgs$1.apply(Typers.scala:115)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.applyImplicitArgs(Typers.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:760)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:732)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit1(Implicits.scala:484)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.typedImplicit0(Implicits.scala:449)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Implicits$ImplicitSearch$$typedImplicit(Implicits.scala:376)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Implicits$ImplicitSearch$ImplicitComputation.tryImplicitInfo$1(Implicits.scala:668)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetSlotInfo(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:767)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.access$100(SunPKCS11.java:42)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$TokenPoller.run(SunPKCS11.java:700)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

{/Users/axaluss/LIBRARIES/scalala-Scalala-f2876c8/scalala-Scalala-f2876c8}
###[ axaluss ]:
```

I dont know much about SBT so I dont know what I am doing wrong.
The sbt file I changed to:

```
java $SBT_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xss4M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:NewSize=512M -XX:NewRatio=3 -jar `dirname $0`/project/sbt-launch-0.7.5.jar "$@"
```

Build.properties:

```
#Project properties
#Mon Apr 11 02:52:55 PDT 2011
project.organization=org.scalala
project.name=scalala
sbt.version=0.7.4
project.version=1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT
def.scala.version=2.9.0
build.scala.versions=2.9.0
project.initialize=false
```

The same problem occured when compiling for scala 2.8.1.

How can I manage to compile scalala?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to increase heap size a bit, in sbt put:

```
-Xmx1524M
```

Comment: In Windows , edit sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt and add that line

Answer (score 4):

`sbt` command can read JAVA_OPTS or SBT_OPTS environment variable. Co you can try:

$ JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1524M

If that doesn't work and you are using OpenJDK on a Linux based OS, then you can also try this:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Answer (score 1):

Just setting `SBT_OPTS` may not work as the `JAVA_OPTS` appear after those and at least my `java version "1.7.0_80"` uses the last flag to set the heapsize.